# Strings and variables

Tags: actionscript-3, function, variables

My Code:

```
var nameOfMc:String = "";

function moverMc(nameOfMc:String):void {
    nameOfMc.play();
}

function handleCollision( e:Event ):void{
    var _point:Point = localToGlobal(new Point(mouseX,mouseY));

    if(bigCircle_mc.hitTestPoint(_point.x,_point.y,true)){
           output_txt.text = "BIGCIRCLE"
           nameOfMc = "bigCircle_mc";
           moverMc(nameOfMc);
    }else{
        if(circle_mc.hitTestPoint(_point.x,_point.y,true)){
               output_txt.text = "CIRCLE"
               nameOfMc = "circle_mc";
               moverMc(nameOfMc);
        }else{
            if(rect_mc.hitTestPoint(_point.x,_point.y,true)){   
                output_txt.text = "RECT"
                nameOfMc = "rect_mc"
                moverMc(nameOfMc);
            }else{
                output_txt.text = ""
                stopAll();
                nameOfMc = ""
            }
        }
    }
```

My Problem:

In function moverMc I want Flash to do the same as "bigCircle_mc.play();" if the mouse is over the big circle for example, "rect_mc.play();" if mouse over rectangle...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `moverMc` function is wrong: `nameOfMc` is a string, not a display object so you cannot play it: the `String` type doesn't have a `play()` method.

What you need to do is find the `DisplayObject` instance that has the name contained in the `nameOfMc` variable. (Movie clips are display objects.)

To find a `DisplayObject` by its name, you can use the [getChildByName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29) function on the container that contains the movie clip that you're looking for. (For example, the `Stage` can be this container but it can be any other `DisplayObjectContainer` in the display chain - if your clip is nested inside several other clips, you'll have several `DisplayObjectContainer` instances in the display chain.)

So your function would be something like this:

```
function moverMc(nameOfMc:String):void
{
    var oClip:DisplayObject = theStage.getChildByName(nameOfMc);

    if((oClip != null) && (oClip is MovieClip))
    {
        // You need to cast oClip to MovieClip because getChildByName()
        // returns DisplayObject (the base type of MovieClip) but
        // not all DisplayObjects have a timeline.
        (oClip as MovieClip).play();
    }
}
```

The `theStage` variable is a global variable (of type `Stage`) that you have to set to the stage of your Flash movie when it starts. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153111/how-to-access-stage-in-a-class-that-is-not-a-displayobject) for more details on how to do it.

**Edit:** after the OP's comment I added a version that doesn't need the stage; this just uses the current DisplayObjectContainer to search for children. (`Stage` is just the top-level display object container but all display objects that can have nested display objects are display object containers.)

```
function moverMc(parentOfMc:DisplayObject, nameOfMc:String):void
{
    var oClip:DisplayObject = parentOfMc.getChildByName(nameOfMc);

    if((oClip != null) && (oClip is MovieClip))
    {
        // You need to cast oClip to MovieClip because getChildByName()
        // returns DisplayObject (the base type of MovieClip) but
        // not all DisplayObjects have a timeline.
        (oClip as MovieClip).play();
    }
}
```

You'd call this version like so:

```
nameOfMc = "circle_mc";
moverMc(this, nameOfMc);
```

`this` in the current context refers to the current display object container - this could be the stage or it could be a display object on the stage. You're already using `this` in your code (perhaps without realizing): the `localToGlobal` call is really `this.localToGlobal`.

Comment: Could you explain this theStage variable? I created a new class (according to this page: https://github.com/inruntime/AS3-Global-Object) but I really don't know how things will join together.

Comment: @as3learner I updated my answer with a version of the function that doesn't rely on the stage.